# I'm trying to create this model for 3d printing. Blender says I have zero faces even though they have area. How do I fix this?

Tags: 3d-printing

I started off with a plane and applied the solidify modifier to it so that it was 1.5 mm thick. I used plane cut to cut off some corners and now blender says I have zero faces made from those cuts. What are zero faces and how do I fix this?

[image: Highlighted faces are the zero faces]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is telling you there are zero area faces present, and that tool will  highlight them if you click on the actual button that is reporting them . You can probably simply delete the faces it has highlighted and all will be well.

Maybe a better approach would be to select all of the faces in the object (in edit mode) and then go to Mesh -> Clean Up -> Degenerate Dissolve, which will dissolve all zero area faces and zero length edges ....

Comment: The thing is, those aren't the only faces marked that way. of the other pieces you see in the screenshot, those are all marked zero faces. I'm not sure what or how I created these zero area faces so I have no idea how to make the rest of the geometry if I don't know how to avoid it. I noticed that they seem to all be from places that I separated the mesh at and either filled holes or joined meshes at but I'm not sure then how I could do those things without creating a zero face